# docker build stuck at stage "RUN conda install -y pip ipython python=3.6"

Tags: python, docker, anaconda

I am following PacktPublishing's *Bioinformatics with Python Cookbook*.
I have installed python through Anaconda and was at this stage:

```
docker build -t bio https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PacktPublishing/Bioinformatics-with-Python-Cookbook-Second-Edition/master/docker/Dockerfile
```

The problem is, the build is stuck at stage 8/19 => [7/17] RUN conda install -y pip ipython python=3.6
The last line in the terminal is

```
# Examining conflict for filelock conda-build anaconda:   0%|          | 0/264 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

I am assuming that this problem is due to the clash between the already installed python(Python 3.8.10) via anaconda and the building attempt at installing python via pip.

However, I am not sure because the book did instruct to install Python with Anaconda in the previous pages.
This might not even be a problem, just taking a long time, which the book has warned about.

Comment: From my test, it's not stuck, it just take ages. I stopped while it was examining conflict 9/264 after about 2h of build... You should probably address the problem to the authors of the book.

Comment: @Zeitounator Okay thanks for checking it out. Mine's stuck at 264 as well. I'll let it run overnight and see

Comment: update: been 36744.3s (approx. 10h), at 11% (30/264).